# Como Fazer um replace no XML C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um método que recebe alguns parâmetros, gostaria de dar um replace em algumas informações do xml, no momento eu só consigo remover e adicionar novas informações

```
   private void CriacaoDoConfirmarLogin(string CaminhoArquivoParaLeitura, string NomeCaminhoParaArquivoSaida, string Desafio)
        {
            //remove o conteudo do corpo do arquivo de retorno do webservice
            //para que eu possa utilizar para enviar outros metodos
            string CaminhoCompletoArquivoConfirmacao = CaminhoArquivoParaLeitura;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(CaminhoCompletoArquivoConfirmacao);
            var todosOsNos = doc.SelectNodes("//*");
            for (int i = 0; i < todosOsNos.Count; i++)
            {
                var element = todosOsNos[i];

                if(element.Name == "ServiceId")
                {
                    element.InnerText.Replace("SolicitaLogon", "ConfirmaLogon");
                }

                if (element.Name == "MsgDesc")
                {
                    element.InnerText.Replace("Solicitação do Desafio de Logon", "Confirmação do Desafio de Login");
                }


                if (element.Name == "Resposta")
                {
                    // pega o parent node
                    XmlNode parent = element.ParentNode;
                    // remove o node
                    parent.RemoveChild(element);

                    //adiciona o node de desafio
                    XmlElement desafioElemento = doc.CreateElement("DesafioAssinado");
                    desafioElemento.InnerText = Desafio;
                    parent.AppendChild(desafioElemento);

                    // grava a saida do arquivo
                    string newXML = doc.OuterXml;
                    doc.Save(NomeCaminhoParaArquivoSaida);
                }

            }

         }
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que a sessão citada é para ser a sua session ID? e não um outro identificador do webservice?

Comment: Complementei a minha pergunta, veja se ficou mais claro agora, agradeço a ajuda

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, ajustei a pergunta, veja se consegue ajudar

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, adicionei o código,

Comment: Sua pergunta está cada vez mais confusa, você tem dois webservices? `ContextoLoginWebService` e objWSProducao?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, eu tenho uma classe  "ContextoLoginWebService " no meu controller eu chamo ela, ou seja, no meu controler Login, estou chamando o meu "ContextoLoginWebService "

Answer (score 1):

Onde você escreveu

```
element.InnerText.Replace("SolicitaLogon", "ConfirmaLogon");
```

escreva

```
element.InnerText = element.InnerText.Replace("SolicitaLogon", "ConfirmaLogon");
```

Answer (score 0):

O método `Replace` não modifica a string original, ele retorna uma nova string com as substituições. Portanto, você precisa atribuir a string resultante de volta ao InnerText.

```
  element.InnerText = element.InnerText.Replace("SolicitaLogon", "ConfirmaLogon");
```

Assim como o amigo Yellow_Submarine escreveu;